# How to use dependency injection for Plugins/Blocks [\Drupal::formbuilder() and \Drupal::config()]?

Tags: 8, forms, blocks, dependency-injection

I cannot get my head around this dependency injection theory. How are we supposed to get the below methods aligned with dependency injection?

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
\Drupal::request();
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\enquirycart\Form\EnquiryForm');
\Drupal::config()
```

Here is a class that I need to fix this warning message when viewed in 
https://pareview.sh/

> "\Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use | | dependency
>   injection instead"

```
    class EnquirycartBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    $default_config = \Drupal::config('enquirycart.settings');

    return [
      'label_display' => FALSE,
      'enquiry_email' => $default_config->get('enquirycart.email'),
    ];

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $builtForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\enquirycart\Form\EnquirycartButtonForm');
    $renderArray['form'] = $builtForm;

    return $renderArray;

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_new = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);

    return $form_new;

  }
```

Comment: This article is one of the best I have seen for DI on blocks or plugins https://chromatichq.com/blog/dependency-injection-drupal-8-plugins

Comment: So, you need to implement ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.

Comment: Big help mate! I had no idea how to do this. definitely the best article... now i see the light :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For future reference, from the link by @Kevin:

> The key to making plugins use dependency injection is to implement the
>   [ContainerFactoryPluginInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/8.2.x). When plugins are created, the code
>   first checks if the plugin implements this interface. If it does, it
>   uses the create() and __construct() pattern, if not, it uses just the
>   __construct() pattern. - [From Acquia's Lesson 11.4 - Dependency injection and plugins](https://docs.acquia.com/article/lesson-114-dependency-injection-and-plugins)

The example code below is written by [Mart Matsoo](https://chromatichq.com/users/mart-matsoo) from [Chromatic](https://chromatichq.com/). Please check the full article here: https://chromatichq.com/blog/dependency-injection-drupal-8-plugins. As @Kevin already mentioned in the comments it is a great article about Depencency Injection in Plugins.

**Dependency Injection example in a block**

Note the injection of the 'current_user' service via `$container->get('current_user')` in the `create()` method. You can pass extra services there.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\heytaco\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a Hey Taco Results Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "heytaco_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("HeyTaco! Leaderboard"),
 * )
 */
class HeyTacoBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * @var $account \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $account;

  /**
   * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param string $plugin_id
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *
   * @return static
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param string $plugin_id
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $account
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, AccountProxyInterface $account) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->account = $account;
  }
```

**Dependency Injection example in a controller**

The same concept applies here, pass extra services via `$container->get()` in the `create()` method.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\heytaco\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Controller routines for HeyTaco! block.
 */
class HeyTacoController extends ControllerBase {

  protected $account;

  public function __construct(AccountInterface $account) {
    $this->account = $account;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to call `parent::__construct()` in your constructor there, or you get weird errors when adding blocks.

Comment: In the first example  do you need to also pass the services in a mytaco.services.yml file?

e.g.  

services:
  heytaco.hey_taco_block:
    class: Drupal\heytaco\HeyTacoBlock
    arguments: ['@current_user']

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @kevin, I managed to get this DI working as i wanted. If anyone wants to check the core services follow the link below.

All the services are listed in the core API https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/8.3.x

Just Posting an example class where it used all the \Drupal services i mentioned in the question. here's how you do it.

```
namespace Drupal\enquirycart\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch;

class EnquirycartBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface, ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {


    /**
     * @var  \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface $formbuilder
     */
    protected $formbuilder;

    protected $configfactory;

    protected $routematch;

    protected $requestmatch;

    /**
    * @param array $configuration
    * @param string $plugin_id
    * @param mixed $plugin_definition
    * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface $form_builder
    */
    public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FormBuilderInterface $form_builder, ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, CurrentRouteMatch $route_match, RequestStack $requestdi) {
        parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);

        $this->formbuilder = $form_builder;
        $this->configfactory = $config_factory;
        $this->routematch = $route_match;
        $this->requestmatch = $requestdi;
       /*  dpm($this->configfactory->get('enquirycart.settings'));     
         dpm($this->routematch->getParameter('node')->getTitle()); 
         dpm($this->requestmatch->getCurrentRequest()->getSession()->get('enquire'));*/
    }

   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
       return new static(
            $configuration,
            $plugin_id,
            $plugin_definition,
            $container->get('form_builder'),
            $container->get('config.factory'),
            $container->get('current_route_match'),
            $container->get('request_stack')   
          );
    }


}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `BlockPluginInterface` since `BlockBase` implements it already.